# Split a list of numbers into multiple groups, constrained by a maximum range, while minimizing variance in resulting lists

Tags: algorithms

**Problem:**

Given a list of numbers, and a single number representing the maximum range in a list, break that list up into the fewest lists that can fit all numbers, while grouping such that each list has the lowest variance possible.

**Examples:**

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, with a max range of 10 can be returned as is since 10-1 is 9 which is less than 10.

With a max range of 5 it *could* be grouped as {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, but since the variance could be minimized *should* be returned as {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}.

A more real world example of the data this algorithm might be processing (though still vastly simplified) would be: {50, 45, 55, 50, 10, 15, 95} with a max range of 10.  Which should return {50, 45, 55, 50}, {10, 15}, {95}.

**Thoughts:**

I'm really struggling with determining the 'center point' for each list.  Dividing the lists into a minimum number of possible lists would be fairly easy by iterating from 1 and incrementing, but those resulting divisions seem useless because I can't determine if they're the best possible groupings.

Comment: Sounds like dynamic programming might be helpful?  Assume the list is sorted: we are basically putting vertical lines between certain elements, to divide the array into chunks.  Consider the first chunk; you are eventually forced to put a line because the maximum difference becomes too large;  the question is, should you put it earlier than this point?  You should only put it earlier if the subproblem with the remainder of the array can be solved with as small a partition, but smaller maximum variance.

Comment: @user111398 Perhaps I'm missing something, but that then requires me solving the entire rest of the problem to determine if the first line should be earlier?  Which would in turn alter the rest of the problem at the same time?

Comment: The rest of the problem here would be with smaller and smaller tails of the list. If you are unfamiliar with dynamic programming, ignore the following and continue thinking of a different solution.  Otherwise, you might try something (along the lines of) $dp[k][v]:=$ minimum partition size for the tail $A[k:end]$ subject to maximum variance $\leq v$.  Then you would be trying to find $dp[1][M]$ where $M$ is the number you are given. And then figure out the transition function for $dp[k][v]$.   That definition for $dp$ is just my guess as to what it should be.  It might have to be refined.

Comment: The problem is not well-defined.  You ask us to both use the fewest lists possible *and* to minimize the variance of each list.  You might not be able to simultaneously minimize both; perhaps there is a solution with fewer lists and higher variance, or more lists and lower variance.  Please [edit] your question to specify it more clearly.  An optimization problem normally needs to identify a single objective function to minimize.  Perhaps you want to minimize the number of lists; and then break ties among solutions by minimizing the sum of the variances of the individual lists?

Comment: I recommend studying the material in https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.